# Rename the Teachers' Lounge

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderation, code-of-conduct, teachers-lounge

I've always found the name of the [Teachers' Lounge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/teachers-lounge) to be mildly condescending, as if those who inhabit it see themselves as holding a superior position over the common users. This isn't what was originally [envisioned](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) with moderators being "human exception handlers", but a system in which moderators are implied to be smarter and/or more educated than ordinary users and are expected to use pedagogical and/or disciplinary tactics to mold users into better users.

Let's get rid of this unnecessary social metaphor and rename the room. To be clear, I'm not proposing that we *get rid* of the room, but that we change the name to something like:

- Moderators Lounge
- Moderators Confidential Chatroom
- Moderation Discussion Center

Comment: I think that Teacher is an *great* term for a moderator.  They are here to help users to learn how to participate on the site and maintain order.  There is an implication that they know more, but that implication is generally true:  They typically know more about how a site works and how it is run.

Comment: People seem to think the TL is somehow far more significant than it is. Yes, a conversation in there was directly connected to the current situation, but apart from that, the TL is nothing but a smaller version of [the Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta). It really is just a chat room in which a few mods hang out. Trying to convert it into something larger than it is seems pointless.

Comment: Perhaps this will disappoint you, but "Tavern on the Meta" isn't really a tavern either.

Comment: But... But... The Tavern contains *users*...

Comment: .... THEN WHAT HAVE PEOPLE BEEN DRINKING?

Comment: Given all of the "If you can't do, teach" rhetoric that gets bandied around these days, I wonder how many people would consider teachers to be 'superior' in any case. Most of the teachers I know just feel battered down and assaulted from every side, be it from students, parents, school administrators, education boards or government policies etc.

Comment: @MarkBooth that sounds rather apropos considering the current climate that moderators are confronted with here ...

Comment: @NathanMerrill I strongly disagree (and I'm a moderator). Mods might in general tend to have a good knowledge of the SE system, but that doesn't usually make us "teachers" of anyone else, except maybe in [tag:support] meta posts. It's also not true in general, as I've seen some mods with shockingly poor knowledge of how SE works. I don't want my mod diamond to imply I know more than others; I'm perfectly willing to be mistaken, to be educated by other users, and all mods should be.

Comment: "Mods with shockingly poor knowledge of how SE works" sounds like a poor mod.  I agree that mods can be mistaken, but I'm also think that teachers can be mistaken as well.

Comment: The position of teacher is not a condescending one; being a teacher doesn't evoke a superior position. It's really more interesting and instructive when both learnee and teachers do not see teachers as superior.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think naming their chat room is something only the participants of a chat room should decide.

Answer (score 38):

Uhm.

Quite honestly?

You're never going to see it until you become a mod. Most people spend their entire lives not knowing it exists.

Also, If we're going to ever rename it.

It should be...

The Mod Squad.

Comment: No.  "The Bat Cave"

Comment: Fortress of Moditude?  Okay, that was bad.

Comment: (@fbueckert to be clear--my upvote on the comment is for "Fortress of Moditude," not for the assessment that it's bad word-play.)

Comment: **Mod**ern Family.

Comment: "*Most people spend their entire lives not knowing it exists.*" this wording unfortunately sounds quite bleak. It suggests there are many, *many* people there with lifespan less than (roughly) a decade. They've been born and died all while TL existed.

Comment: The Mod Squad? And not "The Diamond Mines"?

Comment: I could prefer "principal's office", a bit more business-like.

Answer (score 15):

I have no skin in this game and no strong opinion either way, but as the person who invented this name in a distant past, I thought I'd leave my two cents here.

For me, my experience with teachers has rarely been one of "having power and showing it". The best teachers I've had, both here in Germany and in my 12th grade exchange year in the U.S., always tried to be collaborative with their students and made class about *mutual* learning.

And my limited exposure to *actual* teachers' lounges has seemed much more of a social hangout, and less of the place from the Simpsons where teachers make fun of the students and plot how to best make their lives worse.

So anyway, that's the perspective from which I created that name. But I do acknowledge that probably not everyone has had the same experience with teachers.

Answer (score -4):

> Rename the Teachers' Lounge

This will never happen as the name fits, and there is a bit of tradition here.

But if they were to do so, I think a better name might be *Simm City*.  *Sin City* sounds cool, but may offend some.  Best leave it be.